# MS Access report grouping

Tags: ms-access, report, grouping

I am trying to automate a time-consuming admin function that has to happen weekly, but I can't seem to get it right.

I am including an excerpt from our weekly non-conformance report, which I have been preparing in Word for months
[image: MS Word report]

However, it would be much quicker if this report could be generated straight from the MS Access database.

Everything looks OK if there is only one "corrective" and one "preventative" for each non-conformance. But when multiple actions are generated by a non-conformance, I just can't get the "correctives" to stay together, but separate from the "preventatives" which should also stay together. Here are the exact same non-conformances in my latest attempt at a MS Access report:

[image: MS Access report]

For RN.JS-4920, the singular "preventative" is repeated for each unique "corrective". For RN.JS-4919 the singular "corrective" is repeated for every unique "preventative".

How do I change the grouping to keep the "correctives tabulated together, and the "preventatives" tabulated together?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Providing the SQL that is generating the report would be helpful as well as the headers/table structrues of the root, corrective and preventative tables if any. Also, is there a parent table that defines an overall issue?

Comment: Sounds like two n-to-many relationships are involved. This usually requires subreports. Try with at least one of these two dependent datasets as a subreport.

Comment: If this helps, there are multiple tables in this one database, of which I am using three tables. One is a record of the non-conformances, one is the correctives which refers to the non-conformance number, and one is the preventatives which refers to the non-conformance number as well. Each preventative action gets a unique ID, each corrective action gets a unique ID, but one non-conformance may cause more than one preventative and/or corrective action.

Mike, I have a screenshot of the current header structure, but I can't seem to include it in this post.

Comment: June7, I haven't heard of subreports. I'll look into those. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@June7 was right on the money.

Adding subreports into the main report generated the list as I wanted to present them.

The main report is generated from the non-conformance table.

The "corrective actions" list is a subreport generated from a separate table, but referencing the non-conformance number. The "preventative actions" list is another subreport generated from another separate table, but referencing the non-conformance number.